# Why is silver so volatile compared to the S&P 500?

Tags: markets, precious-metals, silver, volatility

As an example, silver took a 9.4% hit on 9/22/2011, which was a bad market day -- the Dow dropped over 3.5%.

The conventional wisdom is that precious metals like silver are a hedge against a falling market. What are the factors that would make it swing so wildly in value?

Comment: Reopened based on edits to make this a viable question and 3  votes to-reopen subsequent to those edits.  Cleaned up prior comments.

Answer (score 5):

The S&P 500 represents a broadly diversified basket of stocks.  Silver is a single metal.  If all else is equal, more diversification means less volatility.  A better comparison would be the S&P 500 vs. a commodities index, or silver vs. some individual stock.

Answer (score 2):

Silver is a commodity. It's valuable for certain kinds of manufacturing, jewelry, and as a speculative financial instrument or hedge against the dollar.

The S&P 500 includes companies which make money off of mining, manufacturing, medicine, media, technology, banking, dining, agriculture... There's a lot more variety there.

Comment: Thanks.  This question was edited / changed from the original.  My original question was why silver dropped 3 times as much as gold in the recent sell-off (gold drop from summer high of $1900).  More recently comparing the two, I imagine it is because silver got more ahead price-wise than gold did, but am not sure.  In any case, thanks for your comment.